# Iteration of elements to create a list

Tags: python, list

How can I create a list by the iteration of elements that have part of the name in common. Each element is a string as shown a sample below.

```
Test_1 = "AAA"
Test_2 = "BBBB"
```

I know that I can do

```
Test_1 = "AAA"
Test_2 = "BBBB"

final = [Test_1, Test_2]

print(final)

['AAA', 'BBBB']
```

But considering I have a couple of hundreds elements I would like to find a way to create the list I need.

Comment: How are these variables declared? Are there simply hundreds of declarations?

Comment: What do you mean, *exactly* by "I have a couple hundreds of elements"? Do you mean you have several hundred variables? How did  you manage to get yourself in that situation to begin with?

Comment: Yes, there are simple  hundreds of declarations. All of them are as it has been shown in the 2 examples.

Comment: You mean, you wrote in your source code, `Test_1 = "AAA"; ...; Test_200 = "whatever"`?

Comment: Terminology note, **python doesn't have variable declarations**

Comment: Short of writing *another* program to rewrite your source code for you, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: You *could* do something like `items = [v for k,v in globals().items() if k.startswith('Test')]` but fundamentally, you should address this problem in your code where you simply have hundreds of variables in your global scope. They should have been organized into containers *to begin with*. Did you really write out by hand hundreds of variable in a module like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local_vars = locals()

final = [local_vars[x] for x in local_vars  if x.startswith("Test_")]
```

Comment: No problem, but as other comments suggested, you might want to change the underlyng code, so that you dont need to use this kind of "hacks".
Also iyou can mark this answer as accepted if you feel your problem is solved by it,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Let me retell your question:

You have many variables. Their variable names are in some pattern, for example, `Test_[number]`. And then you want to put all of them into a list. Am I right?

So here is my solution:

```py
# Assume all your variables are in global namespace
Test_1 = 'AAA'
Test_2 = 'BBBB'
NotTest_3 = 'CCCCC'
print([v for k, v in globals().items() if k.startswith('Test_')])
```